# How to migrate require import to es6 import with currying

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, import

I am migrating a node/express server to typescript. I could now use import syntax instead of require. However, I used to apply currying to shorten imports. How to translate these imports into es6 imports?

```js
const app = require("express")();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
socketManager(io);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    1. add "type": "module" in package.json
    2. start using 
          import {Name} from './index.js';


For your example : 

import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);
app.set('socketio', io);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your example with a clear translation of the imports above?

Comment: Thank you! Just a last question: why do you use `app.set("socketio", io)`? I have written `app.locals.io = io` to access the io instance everywhere. Is there a difference?